# jqgrid sample using array data, what am I missing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm new in jqgrid, I'm just trying thes example to work. I have a html file only, nothing more. When I ran this file, array data is not showing. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>jqGrid Demos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="lib/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="lib/ui.multiselect.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;   /* Remove body margin/padding */
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden; /* Remove scroll bars on browser window */
            font-size: 75%;
        }
        /*Splitter style */


        #LeftPane {
            /* optional, initial splitbar position */
            overflow: auto;
        }
        /*
         * Right-side element of the splitter.
        */

        #RightPane {
            padding: 2px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .ui-tabs-nav li {position: relative;}
        .ui-tabs-selected a span {padding-right: 10px;}
        .ui-tabs-close {display: none;position: absolute;top: 3px;right: 0px;z-index: 800;width: 16px;height: 14px;font-size: 10px; font-style: normal;cursor: pointer;}
        .ui-tabs-selected .ui-tabs-close {display: block;}
        .ui-layout-west .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { border-bottom: 0px none;}
        .ui-datepicker {z-index:1200;}
    </style>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // We use a document ready jquery function.
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                height: 250,
                colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total', 'Notes'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
                    {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
                    {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
                    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
                    {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
                    {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
                    {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
                ],
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                sortname: 'id',
                sortorder: 'desc',
                viewrecords: true,
                multiselect: true,
                imgpath: "lib/basic/images",
                caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
            });
        });
        var mydata = [
            {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
            {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
            {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
        ];
        for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('addRowData',i + 1, mydata1[i]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
    <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? Have you verified that all the required scripts are properly included?

Comment: i have the js files as per written in the tag <srcript src>. i got this example from http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. I just added some of the js files based on what I saw in other examples that I have searched. So far, I didn't get any javascript errors. It's just that, no data is showing. I can see only the box and its title.

Comment: It seems to me, the for loop is not working at all.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, its a damn typo in the Demo code.

The array that is declared is called mydata, and the array in the loop is mydata1[..] (note that evil 1)

grid.locale-en has to be declared first! Then the Browser's debugger can tell you.

(more 'bugyi's, I have some strange Loading text on the top and a striped gray background.)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a pager when you have not set the pager other needed info like the number of rows and page number. Your loop runs into problems when it can't figure out the values for these variables.

Answer (score 1):

This are the css and js to include that do the trick for me. Very important to include **grid.base.js**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the `colModel` somehow. Check if the script after `colModel` runs. Take only `colModel` out and then check again. I'm also having this problem at the moment.

example:

```
jQuery("#appGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local", //or clientSide
    colNames: ["Patient"],
    colModel:[{name:'pat',index:'pat'}]
});

*some code* <- won't run
```

No wonder the loop doesn't work if the grid won't let you execute code after.

But when I do this:

```
jQuery("#appGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local", //or clientSide
    colNames: ["Patient"]
});

*some code* <- will run after col error message
```

The Grid builds just fine, but the code after it isn't executed at all. I don't know where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

The example code seems to be broken. Try this in the for loop:

```
$("#list").addRowData( i, mydata[i], "last" );
```

Those parameters are: rowId, data, position.

Comment: i can't seem to make this sample to work. i redo my project and followed the jqgrid folder structure as per http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm instruction (under introduction-->installation). if it's not a big job for you, would you be able to give me the correct running html and its prerequisite js files? no php files please. just simply the html file with javascript in it is enough. if i can make this array to work, i will continue my study on json. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to develop the same example but also received same error and after doing lots of try and error , finally i come to the right path.
i am putting my sample example for loading array data in jqgrid.
this is working example.

i have included lots of script file in my head tag because i am not sure about it.
i Remove '<' and '>' tag please add it.
working code is :-

```
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

head

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>    

script type="text/javascript"

    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {       jQuery("#list4").jqGrid
            (
                {
                        data: mydata,
                        datatype: "local",
                        height: 250,
                        colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client'],
                        colModel:[
                            {name:'id',index:'id', width:60},
                            {name:'invdate',index:'invdate' },
                            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100}

                                ],
                                pager: '#pager',
                                rowNum:2,
                                rowList:[10,20,30],
                                sortname: 'id',
                                sortorder: 'desc',
                                viewrecords: true,
                                multiselect: true,
                                imgpath: "themes/basic/images",
                                caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
                }
            );


    var mydata = [  {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"3",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"6",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"},
                    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"}
                    ];


        for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
            jQuery("#list4").addRowData(i, mydata[i]);              
            }//function
    );//ready

script
head

body

This is table

table id="list4"

/table

div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"

/div

This is table

/body
/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array declaration and manipulation loop should be inside of anonymous function `jQuery(document).ready(function(){...})`, and not outside of it.
This way it will be executed after jqQrid initialization and not before.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this friends
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var mydata = [{
    Sno: "1",
    StudentName: "Ricky",
    DateOfJoining: "05/12/2014"
}, {
    Sno: "3",
    StudentName: "Hyden",
    DateOfJoining: "06/12/2014"
}, {
    Sno: "4",
    StudentName: "Gill Crist",
    DateOfJoining:"04/12/2014"
}, {
    Sno: "2",
    StudentName: "Lee",
    DateOfJoining: "07/12/2014"
}];

$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        data: mydata,       
        datatype: "local",        
        colNames: ["Sno", "StudentName", "DateOfJoining"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "Sno", width: 100},
            { name: "StudentName", width: 160 },
            { name: "DateOfJoining", width: 150, align: "right" }           
        ],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 2,
        rowList: [1, 2, 3],
        sortname: "Sno",
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "Student Details"
    }); 
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="grid"></table> 
    <div id="pager"></div> 
</body>
```