# JqGrid is displayed with columns and no json data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

i am trying to bind JSON data to jqgrid. But, i am not getting any data.

here, is my code:

```
$(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url:'<%:Url.Action("LoadData","Home")%>',
                datatype: "JSON",
                mtype: "GET",
                colNames: ["sid","sname"],
                colModel: [
            { name: "sid", width: 55,align:"center"},
            { name: "sname", width: 90,align:"center"},
                          ],
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                pager: "#pager",
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                caption: "My first grid"
            });
        });
```

I am using it in Asp.net MVC Application.

I am able to hit the controller and get the JSON data..but i was unsucessful in displaying data to grid.

I am getting proper json o/p from controller.

My Controller is:

```
public JsonResult LoadData()

   {
        var Data= new DataTable();
        Data= DataModel.LoadData();
        var JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Packages, Formatting.Indented);
        return Json(new
        {
            JsonData
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I think there is error in my JQgrid jquery code. Firtly, i want to implement the jqgrid with minimal configuration.

The JSON response i am getting is:

```
[
  {
    "sid": 2,
    "sname": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "sid": 3,
    "sname": "XYZ"
  },
  {
    "sid": 4,
    "sname": "CBA"
  },
  {
    "sid": 5,
    "sname": "IIT"
  },
  {
    "sid": 6,
    "sname": "NIT"
  }
]
```

This is my HTML Structure:

```
<table id="list">
    </table> 
    <div id="pager"></div>
```

I removed the duplicates from the data i am fetching..

The JSON result, i have checked in Text Visualizer of Visual Studio.Its fine..

Please help..

Comment: Could you include the data returned by `LoadData`? You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler), Firebug or Developer Tools of IE or Chrome to catch the exact HTTP traffic. By the way does `sid` contain unique ids?

Comment: No..sid has duplicates

Comment: Its not possible for me to use Fiddler

Comment: If no fiddler, try using Firefox with firebug or chrome console

Comment: Its not allowing me to download any thing..completely restricted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the reason of your problem is the usage of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. You should return *object* instead of *string*. Try to use

```cs
return Json(Packages, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

directly.

Comment: Still..i am getting empty grid. But, the message No records to view disappeared..now

Comment: @Avinash: **Which jqGrid version you use?** Do you use the current version of jqGrid or some old or retro version? In case of usage old versions you could need to add `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, root: function (obj) { return obj; }}`. Additionally I would recommend you to add `loadonce: true` option, but it don't a part of your main problem.

Comment: I am using 4.5.4 Version

Comment: Do i need to include grid.base.js?

Comment: @Avinash: You need include only `grid.locale-en.js` and `query.jqGrid.min.js` (or `query.jqGrid.src.js`), see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file).

Comment: @Avinash: You can verify on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Avinash.htm) that jqGrid should display **non-empty** grid. I suppose that the response from `'<%:Url.Action("LoadData","Home")%>'` is do not what you posted. I recommend you to verify this in [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler). Alternatively you can just start Developer Tools of IE (by pressing of F12), choose "Network" and press "Start capturing". Then you can examine HTTP traffic and see **the exact response**.

Comment: @Oleg..using list collection solved my problem..i dont know why it is not working for datatable..Thanks Oleg for you suggestions

Comment: Do i need to do any extra processing/code change if my list<items>(data) Conatains null values to bind data to grid

Comment: @Avinash: I think it's not needed in the current version of jqGrid, but I personally would prefer to return empty `List<items>`, which corresponds empty array (`[]`), in case of no data in the grid.

Comment: @Oleg..i mean to say some of the columns of the data might contain null values .. For ex: sid sname (1,null) like this

Comment: @Avinash: You have many options and the result depend on what you want to see in the grid. You can included either items like `{"sid":1, "sname":null}` or just `{"sid":1}`. jqGrid provides many [predefined formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter)  and [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). So you can display the `null` value like you prefer. If you dont specify and formatter then `&#160;` will be displayed for `null`, `undefined` or `""` cell input.

Comment: @ Oleg..Thanks..This is much required for me ..i have to deal with lot of null values

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you have js code in .js file on in .aspx file.

Anyway try this and check the request/response with Firefox/Chrome console

```
$(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url:/Home/LoadData/,
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "GET",
            colNames: ["sid","sname"],
            colModel: [
                      { name: "sid", width: 55,align:"center"},
                      { name: "sname", width: 90,align:"center"},
                      ],
            pager: "#pager",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,              
            caption: "My first grid"
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Comment: I have it in .aspx page

Comment: @Avinash, then your code should work fine if you get the same response posted.

Comment: Can you Please chekc my controller..the return tyep should be JSONresult or ActionResult

Comment: @Avinash, `JsonResult` is a type of `ActionResult` so it shoudnt be a problem, you used correct one

Comment: @Avinash what is your html structure? check that also

Comment: In grid, it is displaying as No Records to View..message

Comment: @Avinash, do onething. Try changing the  `datatype: "local"` and see where the problem is.. in grid construction or a datasource. [Refer this for sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461577/jqgrid-sample-using-array-data-what-am-i-missing)

Comment: @Avinash, add the code you tried for local in your question. I will try to see what is the problem

Comment: @Murali..i have used list<T> collection instead of datatable..and its working. Thanks Murali for your continued support

Comment: Is it the problem of JSON Converter i am using..i.e is NewtonSoft.json..if so can you suggest any other?

Comment: @Avinash, You are using the best JSON library. No need to worry